# Bootstrap modal event doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to bind an some code to trigger when my modal is opened. I have no trouble opening the modal but for some reason i can't figur out my event doesn't triggered.

Here is my modal

```
<div id="details" class="modal fade" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
            <p id="modal-body" class="text-defualt text- text-normal text-left"></p>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JS script i'm trying to get to run

```
<script>
    $(function(){ // let all dom elements are loaded
      $("#details").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
          alert("event fired");
      });
    })
</script>'
```

I'm using bootstrap 3.3 and jQuery v1.11.2

Let me know if any more info would help solve the issue
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your modal isn't visible, hence the `show.bs.modal` event never fires. If you show the modal, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/u1pdunkf/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try below code:
Assuming you are opening modal popup on click of any button; add below code, it should work: 
Refer this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/578/)

```
 <script>
    $(function(){ // let all dom elements are loaded
     $(document).on('show.bs.modal','#details', function () {
        alert('hi');
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code fires the modal and the alert. Did you remember to include JQuery?

Try this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/XaYNWv)**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="details" class="modal fade" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="modal-body" class="text-defualt text- text-normal text-left">I work</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#details").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
      alert("event fired");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/kxr2subr/

```js
$(function(){ // let all dom elements are loaded
  $("#details").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
      alert("event fired");
  });
  
  $('button').click(function(){
   $('#details').modal({show: true});
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button>
Open Modal
</button>

<div id="details" class="modal fade" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
            <p id="modal-body" class="text-defualt text- text-normal text-left"></p>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I guess you are missing `bootstrap.min.js` file.